# why do I have to re-install my bluetooth mouse every time I re-connect it?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I have a MoGo bluetooth mouse.  It's pretty sweet, fits in the PCMCIA slot, charges through the same hole.

I have to remove the device and re-find it every time that I want to use it with my windows 7 machine.  Windows finds it just fine (and instantly), but it doesn't seem to go looking for it  unless it's not installed as a device.

Example:  Use computer with bluetooth mouse.  Turn off computer, pack it up and carry it off somewhere.  Turn on computer.  No mouse is found, the re-sync button on the mouse does nothing in the windows side of things, and I have to remove the device and search for it again to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a happy answer, but I've made it start working.

Apparently I was pushing the pair button when I turned on the mouse.  This was not the correct thing to do.  The correct thing to do is to just eject the mouse and then start using it.  Horray, I did it wrong.